# Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader' . Parameter is not of type Blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I'm using an image cropper to crop an image. I'm using the following library

https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor

I have implemented this correctly and i'm getting the cropped image using this function.

```
handleSave = () => {
  const img = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL();

  this.props.croppedImage(img);
};
```

This is where i have implemented the cropper (2nd component)

```
<CropperTest croppedImage={this.getCroppedImg}/>
```

In the 2nd component i'm doing this

```
getCroppedImg(img) {
    this.props.onImageImgPoll(img);
}
```

I'm calling `onImageImgPoll` in the 3rd component like this

```
onImageImgPoll(event,img) {
        console.log("coming here1");
        event.preventDefault();
        let array = this.state.filepoll.slice();
        let unq_file = img;
        console.log("coming here2");

       /* if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {*/
            console.log("coming here3");

            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = (e) => {
                array.push(unq_file);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(unq_file);
            console.log("coming here4");

            this.setState({
                image: event.target.result,
                filepoll: array,
                filestar: []
            });


    }
```

This is where i get the issue. I get an error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'
```

What seems to be the issue here? Thanks in advance

Comment: is `img` argument a blob? if not, then that's the problem

Comment: According to its name, I will assume that `this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL()` returns a dataURI, i.e a String. So first, I really don't see why you want to pass it through a `FileReader.readAsDataURL` since it's already in dataURI format. And even if `img` were a Blob or File, you don't do anything with the FileReader's result in here. And actually, I don't see where you pass the `event` param, so except if `this.props.onImageImgPoll` is a bound version of `onImageImgPoll`, `img` would actually be undefined.